# Trying to connect with ODBC to AWS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, authentication

I created a SQL Server instance on Amazon web services.  I can remote into it ok.

I created a new login ID and password through the management app, but when I try to connect with the data source administrator in windows I am getting a login failed error.  I have tried this several times so I am sure I am not putting the wrong password in.

I have another sql server set up that I can create a login ID and connect to fine.
Any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Have you reviewed Security Group settings?

Comment: You can check if you can connect to the instance on a specific port with telnet. It's an easy way to check if the problem is on a network ( Security group) level or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

1. Have you opened up port 1433 (or your custom TCP port if you specified one) in the security group associated with your EC2 instance (I assume it's EC2 since you said you can remote in)?
2. Have you created both a SQL Server login *and* a database user? SQL Server requires two objects for a login: A server login object and a database user object. See more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545(v=sql.105).aspx.